Thingsboard chain-rules metadata not being preserved thru different nodes
I have a Thingsboard CE setup working in a server, all working fine with devices, dashboards, telemetry, etc, but when I want an alarm to indicate the tank percentaje, that has been calculated some nodes before (in the same chain), the value shows as NULL

Node ComparaDistancia has the code:


metadata.porcentaje = (3800 - (msg.data_distance - 700)) / 38;
metadata.umbral = 35;
return (metadata.porcentaje < metadata.umbral);



And node CreaMsgTgmOk has the code:


var newMsg = {};
newMsg.text = "**Alarma** de deposito bajo " + metadata.porcentaje;
newMsg.chat_id = XXXXXXX; (hidden intentionally)
return {
    msg: newMsg,
    metadata: metadata,
    msgType: msgType
};



When the code executes I would expect the value of the percentaje of the tank in the message, but I get only:
Alarma de deposito bajo null
Why is the value metadata.porcentaje not being taken from one node to the other?
Thanks

Anyone? Thanks!!

Anyone? Thank you
